# php pagination page without refreshing the page and losing post data

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I am trying to create pagination code without refreshing the page using jquery, php and mysql. I found away to do it but I can't retrieve my post data because they are sent from the previous page the main.php page and the pagination code is in another page called pagination.php. I believe the post data wont be lost if I Integrate the two pages into one but when I tried to make it it didn't work.

main page

```
include('db.php');

$per_page = 1; 
$select_table = "select * from pagination";
$variable = mysql_query($select_table);
$count = mysql_num_rows($variable);
$pages = ceil($count/$per_page)

?>
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Qjuery pagination with loading effect using PHP and MySql</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function Display_Load()
{
    $("#load").fadeIn(1000,0);
    $("#load").html("<img src='load.gif' />");
}
function Hide_Load()
{
    $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
};
$("#paginate li:first").css({'color' : '#FF0084'}).css({'border' : 'none'});
Display_Load();
$("#content").load("pagination.php?page=1", Hide_Load());
$("#paginate li").click(function(){
    Display_Load();
    $("#paginate li")
    .css({'border' : 'solid #193d81 1px'})
    .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});
    $(this)
    .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
    .css({'border' : 'none'});
    var pageNum = this.id;
    $("#content").load("pagination.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());
});});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content" ></div>

<div class="link" align="center">

        <ul id="paginate">
            <?php
            //Show page links
            for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
            {
                echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
            }
            ?>
</ul>   
</div>
  <div style="clear:both"> </div>
<div id="load" align="center" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

pagination page

```
     <?php
include('db.php');

$per_page = 1; 
if($_GET)
{
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
$select_table = "select * from pagination where date = ' =$date' and number ='$number' $start,$per_page";
$variable = mysql_query($select_table);
?>
<table width="800px">
    <?php
    $i=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($variable))
    {
        $name=$row['name'];
        $design=$row['designation'];
        $place=$row['place'];
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td style="color:#999;"><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $design; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $place; ?></td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

I get an error from pagination.php page in this line:

```
$select_table = "select * from pagination where date = ' =$date' and number ='$number' $start,$per_page";
```

that $date and $number variables are undefined variables

Comment: They are undefined so define them

Comment: they are already defined in the main page but when click in the button number 2 in the pagination the data will be lost so I tried to define them in the pagination.php page but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the solution was to remove the pagination page.php file and to add a simple jquery pagination plugin inside the main page, which mean its not necessary to define the post data again.

Answer (score -1):

I'd highly recommend you move from mysql_* to mysqli because you are vulnerable.

```
$select_table = "select * from `pagination` where `date` = '".$date."' and `number` ='".$number."' $start,$per_page";
```

I see an extra = in there at the very least, it is also not concatenated properly. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here `$start,$per_page";`. Also make sure you are escaping your fields and tables with back ticks.

Comment: He never asked a question. I was trying to help him with whatever his error is.

Comment: `"php pagination page without refreshing the page and losing post data"`. But I'll leave it there

Comment: @EternalHour  I am using mysqli but this code is just for testing

Comment: my problem is losing the post data and I want to know how to retrieve it using pagination.php page